# save array of objects with update_option

Tags: php, database, options, array

How do I save an array of objects in Wordpress/PHP via `update_option` ?

What I'm trying to save is something like:

```
update_option('my_option', [ 
 { 
  'c': htmlspecialchars($_POST['hidden_category']), 
  't': htmlspecialchars($_POST['hidden_tags']) 
 }, 
 { 
  'c': htmlspecialchars($_POST['hidden_category_1']), 
  't': htmlspecialchars($_POST['hidden_tags_1']) 
 },
 //etc..
]);
```

`$_POST['hidden_category']` contains a string

while
`$_POST['hidden_tags']` contains an array of strings

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I would apply one of functions serialize() or json_encode() to a value of $_POST['hidden_tags'].

Comment: I see, but the js like `[{ .. }, { .. }, { .. }]` structure itself is something update_option/php/mysql accepts?

Comment: Mentioned functions are returns a string result that you can store in MySQL. When you need to use a stored value you should deserialize() or json_decode().

Comment: I'm trying, but `var_dump(json_decode(get_option( 'my_option' )[0]))` returns null with a var_dump , but `get_option( 'my_option' )` var_dumps `array(1) { [0]=> string(112) "{c: "MyCategory", t: "tag1, tag2, tag3" }" }`

Comment: @Bob thanks I found the issue, it was in the format of the json, now it works